# Tikz picture of two mathematical functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to draw the functions y=(0.05*0.4+0.1*2*x)/(0.05+0.1*2) and x=-0.1/(2*10*(y - 0.1))+y, by using tikz as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1, samples=1000, xlabel={$c$}, ylabel={$s$}]
\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,(0.05*0.4+0.1*2*x)/(0.05+0.1*2));
\addplot[red,  ultra thick] (-0.1/(2*10*(x - 0.1))+x,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I obtained the picture:

[image]

But I'm not sure about the result (tikz seems to have drawn also the asymptote of second function). For me (and Mathematica) the result should be instead the following:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this picture and my tikz code?

Comment: Add appropriate curly brackets: `\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,{(0.05*0.4+0.1*2*x)/(0.05+0.1*2)});
  \addplot[red,  ultra thick] ({-0.1/(2*10*(x - 0.1))+x},x);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ti*k*Z/pgfplots parser gets confused about the brackets, it does not know which of them are delimiters of coordinates or expressions in the functions. So you have to help them a bit by adding curly brackets.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1, samples=1000, xlabel={$c$},
 ylabel={$s$},unbounded coords=discard]
  \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,{(0.05*0.4+0.1*2*x)/(0.05+0.1*2)});
  \addplot[red,  ultra thick,domain=0:0.099] ({-0.1/(2*10*(x - 0.1))+x},x);
  \addplot[red,  ultra thick,domain=0.11:1] ({-0.1/(2*10*(x - 0.1))+x},x);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's clear. Is there a way to remove the asymptote?

Comment: @Mark Sure. (Sorry, was offline.) I removed the red asymptote. If you want to remove the blue one as well, remove `\addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,{(0.05*0.4+0.1*2*x)/(0.05+0.1*2)});`. The red one was because you plotted over a singularity at `x=0.1`, and one easy way to remove it is to add two separate plots that avoid it.